# Custom notification sound will not play

Tags: android, android-notifications

I was using the default notification sounds and vibration using 
`builder.setDefaults(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)`
which worked perfectly.
However I decided I wanted to allow the user to pick a notification using the preference.

This worked for retrieving the users selection, but using this code no sound plays (regardless of selection). I know the sound files exist, as they are shipped with the phone.

```
public void sendNotification(Context context, String sender, long millis)
{
    int num = DATABASE_HELPER.countUnread();
    Log.i("Notification sound", SETTINGS.notification().toString());
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
            .setSound(SETTINGS.notification())
            //.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(sender)
            .setContentText("New Message" + (num > 1 ? "s" : ""))
            .setWhen(millis)
            .setNumber(num);
    builder.setContentIntent(getNotificationIntent(context));
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

This produces the output `content://media/internal/audio/media/18` in the log, the phone vibrates (although it is a different pattern, presumably a difference between the `RingtoneManager` and `Notification` defaults), but no sound is played.

And before people ask, yes I did check the volume/ phone was not on silent etc.

Comment: Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
builder.setSound(alarmSound);

Comment: @N.V.Rao Thanks, but I am trying to use a custom notification sound chosen by the user, not the default sound